# How can I sort a staggered array using an algorithm avoiding array.sort

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

```
jaggedArray[0] = new int[] { 1, 333, 500, 75, 9 };
jaggedArray[1] = new int[] { 0, 2, 4, 6 };
jaggedArray[2] = new int[] { 11, 22 };
```

I wanted to sort the first column to be in a ascending order without using `Array.Sort` ? how can I first sort the column and then print the whole staggered `array` based on that `sort`?

Comment: using some kind of sorting algorithm such as bubble, quick or insertion

Answer (score 2):

Just use Linq OrderBy:

```
jaggedArray = jaggedArray.OrderBy(inner => inner[0]).ToArray();
```